# Qualtrics: How to jointly randomize both text/graphic question and multiple choice question in the same block?

Tags: javascript, title, qualtrics

In Qualtrics,
I have 1 block.
This block has 2 text sections that describe 2 policies.

1 policy contains text under the title "A Living Wage of $15/hour" and the 2nd policy is titled "A Minimum Wage of $10/hour."

These text sections are then followed by a multiple choice section with 4 options:
People Prefer Policy A, People Slightly Prefer Policy A, People Prefer Policy B, People Slightly Prefer Policy B.

I want the policies to be randomly labeled as either "Policy A" or "Policy B" and evenly distributed such that half of the participants see  "A Living Wage of $15/hour" labeled as "Policy A" and the other half sees it as "Policy B" (and vice versa).

I want the policy labeled as "Policy A" (i.e., either "A Living Wage of $15/hour" or "A Minimum Wage of $10/hour") to be random each time, but Policy A always shows up first before Policy B.

how do I do this?

Countless thanks

I've tried chatgpt and working within javascript and display logic to no avail yet